# Анимация при наведении на ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, анимация

Есть страница с 3 блоками. При ховере на каждый блок происходит анимация — изменение цвета бэкграунда и анимация текста(пример, блок 1). В header есть 2 ссылки: `Logo, Link`. При наведении на них, пропадает анимация блоков, состояние блока возвращается к первоначальному состоянию.

Возможно ли, как-то при наведении на эти ссылки сохранять состояние анимации в наведенном блоке?
Спасает `pointer-events: none` на ссылках в хедере. Происходит то, что нужно, но тогда невозможно перейти по ссылкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависит от разметки, по всей видимости ваши ссылки находятся за пределами блока. Один из вариантов это поместить их внутрь блока, тогда будут срабатывать все эффекты. Другие варианты, нужно рассматривать исходя из разметки. Потому что если например ваши ссылки находятся где-нибудь далеко от этих блоков, тогда без js не обойтись.

Comment: l2banners, да, в том и проблема, они в разных блоках

Comment: так а где именно? Ссылки фиксированные и по всему сайту ездят или как, если блоки идут после ссылок на одном уровне то можно достучаться до них через селектор ~

Comment: l2banners, грубо говоря 
<div.header><a>Logo</a><a>Link</a></div>
<div><div.block1></div></div>
<div><div.block2></div></div>
<div><div.block3></div></div>
Т.е. хедер и блоки лежат в разных row. А header еще и absolute

Comment: Тогда наверное кроме js ничего и не придумаешь. Но опять же эффект наведения нужен как я понимаю только тогда когда ссылки находятся на фоне блоков?

Comment: т.е. верхние ссылки всегда находятся наверху по краям, я навожу на первый блок он меняет цвет, но стоит навести на лого и анимация пропадает с первого блока. Естественно потому что они изолированы друг от друга. Я так и думал, что без js никак. Но надежда, что вдруг какое то решение есть, которое я не знаю, была)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое решение на jquery. Я прокомментировал все этапы. Удобнее и понятнее смотреть в развернутом окне. Сам эффект наведения работает за счет добавления/удаления класса у анимируемого блока. Структура html может быть значительно сложней.

```js
$(function() {
  // В переменную $item записываем блоки для которых будем имитировать hover
  var $item = $(".item");

  
  // В переменную classActive записываем класс
  // который мы будем добавлять/удалять 
  // у наших блоков, вместо hover
  var classActive = "item_hov";

  // На шапку вешаем событие mousemove, 
  // то есть будем следить за курсоров внутри header
  $(".header").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    // Когда курсор внутри header, проходим циклом
    // по всем отслеживаемым блокам
    // и сравниваем координаты крайних точек каждого
    // с координатыми курсора
    for (var i = 0; i < $item.length; i++) {
      var left = $item.eq(i).offset().left;
      var right = left + $item.eq(i).width();
      var top = $item.eq(i).offset().top;
      var bottom = top + $item.eq(i).height();
      if (
        event.pageX >= left &&
        event.pageX <= right &&
        event.pageY >= top &&
        event.pageY <= bottom
      ) {
        // Если координаты курсора внутри
        // в пределах координат сравниваемого блока
        // то добавляем этому блоку класс
        // записаный в переменную classActive
        $item.eq(i).addClass(classActive);
        //И выходим из цикла
        break;
      } else {
        // Иначе удаляем у всех блоков classActive
        $item.removeClass(classActive);
      }
    }
  });

  // Если мы уводим курсор с header
  // удаляем у всех блоков класс
  // записаный в переменную classActive
  $(".header").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $item.removeClass(classActive);
  });

  // Добавляем блоку на который навели курсор
  // класс записаный в переменную classActive
  $item.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass(classActive);
  });

  // Удаляем блоку м которого увели курсор
  // класс записаный в переменную classActive

  $item.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass(classActive);
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0,0, 0.5);
}

.header a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 500px;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}

.item_hov {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
  <a href="">Ссылка 2</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо тебе большое! Убрал ховеры в стилях, прицепил к классу, подцепил твой код и теперь все работает как надо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот нажмите на Выполнить код и посмотрите ... у меня работает анимация ...и даже при наведении на ссылки ....

**Если структура кода отличается от вашей то исправьте ваш вопрос таким способом что бы можно было увидеть Вашу проблему**

```css
.items{
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
}
.item{
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
  border-left:1px solid #fbfbfb;
  border-right:1px solid #fbfbfb;
  transition:all .4s linear;
}
.item:hover{
  background:blue;
}
a{
  font-size:2em;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```